# Christmas Tree in Kotlin

Tags: functional-programming, ascii-art, kotlin

Please review my code for printing a Christmas Tree.
The idea was to merge some functional programming ideas (immutability, streams) and OOP (every *thing* is a small object).

I'm looking for a review focused on readability of the code.

Here is a output from the code:

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
```

And the code:

```
fun main(a: Array<String>) {
    print(Tree(height = 5))
}

class Tree(val height: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return (0..height - 1)
                .map { i ->
                    Stage(i, height)
                }
                .joinToString(
                        separator = "\n",
                        postfix = "\n"
                )
    }
}

class Stage(val idx: Int, val height: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        val trunkWidth = TrunkWidth(idx)
        val margin = Margin(MarginWidth(TreeWidth(height), trunkWidth).value())
        return listOf(
                margin,
                Trunk(trunkWidth.value()),
                margin
        ).joinToString(separator = "")
    }

}

class MarginWidth(val tree: TreeWidth, val trunk: TrunkWidth) {
    fun value(): Int {
        return (tree.value() - trunk.value()) / 2
    }
}

class TreeWidth(val height: Int) {
    fun value(): Int {
        return height * 2 - 1;
    }
}

class TrunkWidth(val idx: Int) {
    fun value(): Int {
        return 1 + 2 * idx
    }
}

class Trunk(val size: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return UniformString(size, "*").toString()
    }
}

class Margin(val size: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return UniformString(size, " ").toString()
    }
}

class UniformString(val size: Int, val char: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return (0..size - 1)
                .map { char }
                .joinToString(separator = "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. "args" is more common and descriptive than "a" in a `main` function signature
2. "\n" is system-dependent; I recommend using `System.lineSeparator()` instead
3. `joinToString` can be used with a `transform` instead of first mapping an `Iterable` using a `transform` and then calling `joinToString`. e.g.:

   ```
   (0..height - 1).map { i -> Stage(i, height) }.joinToString()
   ```

   can be written as

   ```
   (0..height - 1).joinToString { i -> "${Stage(i, height)}" }
   ```

   which will avoid creating an intermediary list (small optimization in this case).
4. Perhaps a minor issue but I personally prefer using "index" instead of "i" or "idx" to avoid any ambiguity. ["idx"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=idx) actually has several meanings.
5. I find `buildString` used with [`repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html) to often be more readable than `Iterable` combined with `joinToString`:

   ```
   buildString { repeat(height) { index -> appendln(Stage(index, height)) } }
   ```
6. I also find `buildString` to be more suitable than `joinToString(separator = "")`:

   ```
   return buildString {
       append(margin)
       append(Trunk(trunkWidth.value()))
       append(margin)
   }
   ```
7. If you are going to have classes for computed numbers than I find `toInt` (like `AtomicInteger.toInt`) much more readable than `value` for `MarginWidth`, `TreeWidth`, etc.
8. Naming an instance of `TreeWidth` as simply "tree" is rather confusing, I recommend using type names (at least the end of them) at the end of instance names (e.g. "stageTreeWidth", "stageWidth", "treeWidth", or simply "width").
9. Kotlin has a neat `String.repeat` function to simplify building strings with a repeated char sequence. e.g.:

   ```
   "*".repeat(size)
   ```
10. Technically a "trunk" does not include the branches, etc. so "TrunkWidth" and "Trunk" are kind of confusing names for this. You might consider "LayerWidth" and "Layer".
11. I see very little point to all these classes as they do not serve much purpose. A class with a single method to define its single behavior might as well be a method. If `Stage`, `MarginWidth`, `Margin`, etc. will be used by methods other than `Tree.toString` then it might make sense to have these as classes. If they are simply to build a string representation then I would drop them in favor of inline calculations (OOP does not mean that "every *thing* is a small object"; e.g. "height" and "width" may be attributes of objects but are not necessarily objects themselves).

    This entire collection of classes can be reduced to the following (assuming no other code is using `Stage`, `Margin`, etc.):

    ```
    class Tree(val height: Int) {
        override fun toString(): String {
            return buildString {
                val treeWidth = height * 2 - 1
                repeat(height) { index ->
                    val layerWidth = 1 + 2 * index
                    val marginWidth = (treeWidth - layerWidth) / 2
                    val marginString = " ".repeat(marginWidth)
                    val layerString = "*".repeat(layerWidth)
                    append(marginString)
                    append(layerString)
                    append(marginString)
                    appendln()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ```

    If `Tree.height` is never used then even `Tree` itself can be eliminated and the tree string building logic can be placed in a single function:

    ```
    fun buildTreeString(height: Int) = buildString {
        repeat(height) { layerIndex ->
            val layerWidth = 1 + 2 * layerIndex
            val marginWidth = height - layerIndex - 1
            repeat(marginWidth) { append(' ') }
            repeat(layerWidth) { append('*') }
            repeat(marginWidth) { append(' ') }
            appendln()
        }
    }
    ```

    And you can even pre-compute the required capacity to avoid unnecessary array copying while building the string:

    ```
    fun buildTreeString(height: Int): String {
        return buildString(height * (2 * height - 1 + System.lineSeparator().length)) {
            repeat(height) { layerIndex ->
                val layerWidth = 1 + 2 * layerIndex
                val marginWidth = height - layerIndex - 1
                repeat(marginWidth) { append(' ') }
                repeat(layerWidth) { append('*') }
                repeat(marginWidth) { append(' ') }
                appendln()
            }
        }
    }

    inline fun buildString(capacity: Int, builderAction: StringBuilder.() -> Unit)
            = StringBuilder(capacity).apply(builderAction).toString()
    ```

    If however you actually need/want classes for tree components then I recommend making those components (or collections of those components) members of a `Tree` class (e.g. a `Tree` has `layers: List<Tree.Layer>`).